# SQL Server 2005: Why would a delete from a temp table hang forever?

Tags: sql-server-2005, debugging

```
DELETE FROM #tItem_ID
WHERE #tItem_ID.Item_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Item_ID
                                  FROM Item_Keyword 
                                  JOIN Keyword ON Item_Keyword.Keyword_ID = Keyword.Record_ID
                                 WHERE Keyword LIKE @tmpKW)
```

The Keyword is %macaroni%. Both temp tables are 3300 items long. The inner select executes in under a second. All strings are nvarchar(249). All IDs are int.

Any ideas?  I executed it (it's in a stored proc) for over 12 minutes without it finishing.

Comment: BTW, `"forever"`, is a _long_, _long_... time ;-) Are you sure?

Comment: I scripted the entire database, reloaded all the records with bulk copy, and the issue disappeared.  Any thoughts now?  I restarted SQL server several times to clear any "deadlocks" but the issue remained.

Comment: forever can also mean "continually", where it doesn't happen all the physical time, but every time it happens. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that has a lock on the table could prevent the query from proceeding.  Do you have any other sessions open in SSMS where you have done something to one of the tables?

You can also use the system sproc `sp_who2` to see if there are any locks open.  look in the column `BlkBy` and see if anything is hanging on a lock held by another process.

Answer (score 2):

The classic case where SQL Server "hangs" is when you open a transaction but don't commit or rollback.  Don't get so wrapped up in your actual delete (unless you are working with a truly huge dataset) that you fail to consider this possibility.

Comment: Unless there is an implied transaction, no begin transaction exists in the sp.  Oddly, the identical database on my machine executes immediately.

Answer (score 2):

When i run into issues like this i fire up [SQL Heartbeat](http://www.sqlsolutions.com/products/Heartbeat/) and it can show me what is causing the conflict. This also shows deadlocks related to transactions that were not closed correctly as Mark states above.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to read up on [deadlocking...](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/deadlocks_p1.aspx)

** Ignore my answer - I'm leaving it up so that Dr. Zim's comment is preserved, but it is incorrect **

Comment: Deadlocks on a temporary table that is isolated to the individual process?

Comment: Deadlock detection should kick in much before 12 mins are elapsed I think?

Comment: Actually Dr. Zim has a good point there - I'm wrong. 

Been a while since I used MS-SQL, but deadlocking detection ain't all that... In my old job we've seen it hang a server...

Comment: Many people are suggesting the deadlock.  I add this to you can see it.  I actually scripted and recreated the database, then bulk copy imported the records again, and the issue went away.  I restarted the SQL service to ensure no deadlocks existed.